# My css rules apply to all input elements except for one I made during the script

Tags: javascript, html, css

For some reason, the input I created with the table is NOT AS LONG. I used `normalize.css` too, and all that did is made it slightly longer. I need it to fill the page and I have no idea where to even begin wording my google searches for such an issue.

Also, all of the css rules DO apply except for width (i think). My dynamically created input is just not as long as the others. Blows my mind.

```
function makeInput() {
var myInput = document.createElement("input");
myInput.type = "text";
myInput.value = "Here is where the quetsion goes";
return myInput;
}

function makeTable() { // make table with one row and one td


var myTable = document.createElement('table'); // Create table called myTable
var myRow = document.createElement('tr'); // create row called myTr
myTable.id = "myTalbe"
myTable.border = "0"
myTable.cellspacing = "2"
myTable.cellpadding = "0"
myTable.width = "100%"
myTable.type = "text"

var td1 = document.createElement('td'); // td1 for input
var td2 = document.createElement('td'); // td2 for button

var text1 = document.createTextNode('Here is my text');

td1.appendChild(makeInput()); // append makeInput();
td2.appendChild(makeButton()); // append my input form to td1

myRow.appendChild(td1);
myRow.appendChild(td2); // append td1 element to my table


myTable.appendChild(myRow); //

document.body.appendChild(myTable);
}
```

Game plan: `makeInput()` returns an input element. `makeTable()` puts it inside a `<td>`. `makeTable()` runs under `$(document).ready` (jQuery).

I have 5 other inputs on the page. All of which are managed by this:

```
input[type="text"] {
height: 30px;
display: block;
margin: 0;
width: 98%;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
appearance: none;
box-shadow: none;
border-radius: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
table tr td input[type="text"] {
height: 30px;
display: block;
margin: 0;
width: 98% !important;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
appearance: none;
box-shadow: none;
border-radius: none;
}
```

You try this css....

Comment: Or show me your code in fiddle i will give the result.

Answer (score 0):

Tables come with spacing between cells, borders, and padding on cells. Reset those to 0 and it should fill the available space, matching the other inputs.  Since there is a cell next to the inputs they will not be the exact same width, since the other cell pushes it to be narrower, but they will line up at least.

```js
function makeInput() {
  var myInput = document.createElement("input");
  myInput.type = "text";
  myInput.value = "Here is where the quetsion goes";
  return myInput;
}

function makeTable() { // make table with one row and one td
  console.log("Make a table");
  var myTable = document.createElement('table'); // Create table called myTable
  var myRow = document.createElement('tr'); // create row called myTr
  myTable.id = "myTalbe"
  myTable.border = "0"
  myTable.cellspacing = "2"
  myTable.cellpadding = "0"
  myTable.width = "100%"
  myTable.type = "text"

  var td1 = document.createElement('td'); // td1 for input
  var td2 = document.createElement('td'); // td2 for button

  var text1 = document.createTextNode('Here is my text');

  td1.appendChild(makeInput()); // append makeInput() to td1
  td2.appendChild(makeButton()); // append makeButton() to td2

  myRow.appendChild(td1); // append td1 to the row
  myRow.appendChild(td2); // append td2 to the row

  myTable.appendChild(myRow); // append the row to the table

  document.body.appendChild(myTable); // append the table to the body
}

function makeButton() {
  var myButton = document.createElement('button');
  var txt = document.createTextNode('Test');
  
  myButton.appendChild(txt);
  return myButton;
}

$(document).ready(makeTable);
```

```css
button, input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

input[type="text"] {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  appearance: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

td {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" value="Made on load" />
<input type="text" value="This one was made on load too" />
```